# Active Directory, gssapi, PostgreSql 12 помогите настроить авторизацию

Tags: windows, ubuntu, postgresql, active-directory

Есть задача: настроить бесшовную авторизацию для приложения, которое в качестве СУБД postgreSQL 12.
Делал согласно вот этому мануалу: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/gssapi-auth

Что сделано.

0. Установлена Ubuntu 18
1. Установлен PostgreSQL 12
2. Создан keytab файл
3. Он указан в конфиге postgres postgres.conf
4. host all all 0.0.0.0/0 gss include_realm=1 krb_realm=DOMAIN.COM
5. Настройки для домена прописаны в файле /etc/krb5.conf
6. Сервер c PostgreSQL введен в домен
7. На сервере созданы учетные записи пользователей
8. Если на машине с Postgres авторизоваться пользователем из AD и попробовать зайти без логина и пароля - то сервер пускает

Когда пытаюсь зайти на машине под управление Windows.
То получаю от клиента следующие сообщение.

````
psql: ошибка: ошибка продолжения в SSPI: The specified target is unknown or unreachable
 (80090303)```

А в логах сервера мне выходит вот это:
````

2021-02-03 15:58:59.533 UTC [92998] adm_postgresql@gis FATAL:  28000: GSSAPI authentication failed for user "adm_postgresql"
2021-02-03 15:58:59.533 UTC [92998] adm_postgresql@gis DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 104: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 gss include_realm=1 krb_realm=DOMAIN.COM"
2021-02-03 15:58:59.533 UTC [92998] adm_postgresql@gis LOCATION:  auth_failed, auth.c:333

```
Подскажите в какую сторону копать, что решить вопрос с авторизацией?
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение вопроса. Вместо ip сервера нужно указывать имя хоста - тогда gssapi работает